# Dynamically created list is being duplicated

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript function which adds items based on an object-filled (Javascript) array.

Here's what the function to add the items looks like:

```
function appendShopItem(shopItem)
{
    // Create the list item:
    item = document.createElement( 'li' );

    // Set its contents:
    item.appendChild( document.createTextNode( 
        shopItem.name + ' - ' + shopItem.cost + ' Gold'
    ) );

    // Add it to the list:
    list.appendChild( item );

    var radio = document.createElement( 'button' );
    var text = document.createTextNode( "Buy " + shopItem.name + " for " + shopItem.cost + " Gold");
    radio.name = 'shop';
    radio.value = shopItem.name;
    radio.id = "shop";
    radio.style.display = "inline-block";
    radio.style.textAlign = "left";
    radio.onclick = function () {
        addValue( shopItem );
    };

    var lineBreak = document.createElement("BR");
    document.body.appendChild(lineBreak);
    radio.appendChild( text );
    document.getElementById("centeredDiv").appendChild( radio );
}
```

`shopItem` would be an object in the array, for example:

```
shopItems = [
    { name: "Potion", cost: 10, description: "A healing liquid." },
];
```

This creates something like this:

[image: List being created]

If I click `Leave Shop`, it hides the shop. If I then click `Enter Shop`, it turns into this:

[image: Duplicated]

As you can see, the `Potion` has been duplicated. If I do it again, three appear, and so on and so forth. *Can someone help me so that it only displays one*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

I added an `id` to the `list` item itself, rather than its `contents`, then destroyed it later on.